# Unable to update EclipseLink with M2Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, repository, eclipselink, m2eclipse

I am using Eclipse with Maven (using m2eclipse) and attempting to add the EclipseLink repository.

Within my pom.xml I have set the following:

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>eclipselink</id>
    <url>http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.phpr=1&amp;nf=1&amp;file=/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

I then navigate to the Maven Repository Window and right click the repository and select Full Index Enabled.

This results in the following message being displayed:

```
4/23/11 1:45:53 PM BST: Updating index eclipselink|http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?r=1&nf=1&file=/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo
4/23/11 1:45:54 PM BST: Unable to update index for eclipselink|http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?r=1&nf=1&file=/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo
```

Any help in solving this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/a/13362961/715269

Answer (score 0):

If you call that page you will get an 404 page not found...so the url must be wrong.

Comment: The url supplied has the & replaced with &amp; to make the XML parseable. Within the Maven repository window it displays the repository and when you right click and 'copy url' it produces the following: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?r=1&nf=1&file=/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo ... which is correct

Comment: Ah ok. oversight...sorry my fault. But the contents does not show any index so the message is Ok for me...May be you have to define the repository type to legacy.

Answer (score 0):

There may not be anything to worry.  It is possible that Eclipselink repository is not having a repository index file which is requested by m2eclipse.

What is important is to check if dependencies specified in your pom, present in Eclipselink repository are getting downloaded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in URL:
It should be:
`http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?r=1&nf=1&file=/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo`

You missed question mark.
Source:
[Can't find the "org.eclipse.persistence" Maven dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122135/cant-find-the-org-eclipse-persistence-maven-dependency)